# REST api alternative for describe command

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How I can call via rest api this commands:

```
$ kubectl describe po xyz

$ kubectl describe svc xyz

$ kubectl describe node zyx
```

I need get service endpoints and node capacity usage. But I can't find in docs how I can do this. GET command not provides this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `kubectl --v=8 ...` for fun and profit!

For eg: a describe pod is actually a combination of results from the pod and the events APIs:

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xyz
GET /api/v1/namespaces/default/events?fieldSelector=involvedObject.name%3Dxyz%2CinvolvedObject.namespace%3Ddefault%2CinvolvedObject.uid%3Dd4605fd6-b152-11e6-a208-02e9103bab42
```